# Delphi marquee progress bar no animation

Tags: delphi, progress-bar

In my delphi project, I use progressbar. I set its style to marquee:
`progressbar1.Style:=pbstMarquee;`

Everything works fine until I apply any appearance style for the project. Then there's no more animation on the progress bar. I've tried several appearance styles/themes. Tested on a new empty project just to make sure that some settings in my project aren't messed up. Results are the same.

If I set:
`ProgressBar1.StyleElements := [];`
Animation is back, and everything works, but progressbar losses all its appearance colors and doesn't match the rest of the application.
Any idea why this is happening?

Default style:

[image]

Style applied:

[image]

After adding ProgressBar1.StyleElements := [];:
[image]

Comment: The problem with VCL styles is that it relies on static images. So I don't think it is possible to have animated progress bar while using VCL styles that is unless you rewrite the whole progress bar by yourself to add the needed animation. Perhaps it might be best to search around the web if such modified progress bar already exists.

Comment: Try to use TActivityIndicator instead of TProgressBar with Marquee style. Yes, it's not same, but could helps.